# Web service callout failed error when trying to update duplicate rule

Tags: apex, soap-api, metadata-api, webservices, metadata

I am using apex-mdapi (https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to update the duplicate rules from metadata API. While I am trying to read the metadata, I am not able to update the metadata (duplicate rule) using this because of the error:

```
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Must specify a {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type attribute value for the {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}metadata element faultcode=soapenv:Client faultactor=
```

**My code snippet is:**

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
MetadataService.DuplicateRule rule = (MetadataService.DuplicateRule) service.readMetadata('DuplicateRule', new String[] { 'Contact.Contact_Duplicate_Email' }).getRecords()[0];
rule.isActive = false;
System.debug('rule metadtaa : '+rule);
List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { rule });
System.debug('results : $$$ '+results);
```

This is the duplicateRule class which I have edited in the mdapi:

```
public class DuplicateRule extends metadata{
        public String type = 'DuplicateRule';
        public String fullName; 
        public String actionOnInsert;
        public String actionOnUpdate;
        public String alertText;
        public String description;
        public MetadataService.DuplicateRuleFilter duplicateRuleFilter;
        public MetadataService.DuplicateRuleMatchRule[] duplicateRuleMatchRules;
        public Boolean isActive;
        public String masterLabel;
        //public String[] operationsOnInsert;
        //public String[] operationsOnUpdate;
        public String securityOption;
        public Integer sortOrder;
        private String[] type_att_info = new String[]{'xsi:type'};
        private String[] actionOnInsert_type_info = new String[]{'actionOnInsert',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] actionOnUpdate_type_info = new String[]{'actionOnUpdate',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] fullName_type_info = new String[]{'fullName',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] alertText_type_info = new String[]{'alertText',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','true'};
        private String[] description_type_info = new String[]{'description',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','true'};
        private String[] duplicateRuleFilter_type_info = new String[]{'duplicateRuleFilter',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','true'};
        private String[] duplicateRuleMatchRules_type_info = new String[]{'duplicateRuleMatchRules',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','-1','true'};
        private String[] isActive_type_info = new String[]{'isActive',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] masterLabel_type_info = new String[]{'masterLabel',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','false'};
       // private String[] operationsOnInsert_type_info = new String[]{'operationsOnInsert',W3_URI,null,'0','-1','false'};
       // private String[] operationsOnUpdate_type_info = new String[]{'operationsOnUpdate',W3_URI,null,'0','-1','false'};
        private String[] securityOption_type_info = new String[]{'securityOption',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] sortOrder_type_info = new String[]{'sortOrder',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{SOAP_M_URI,'true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'actionOnInsert','actionOnUpdate','fullName','alertText','description','duplicateRuleFilter','duplicateRuleMatchRules','isActive','masterLabel','securityOption','sortOrder'};
    }
```

How do I have to fix this error?